# display tweets for last 24 hours

Tags: php, json, twitter

Trying to return all tweets in the last 24hours from a user, but not sure how to do it, this is the code i have so far and that is just to get the last 5 tweet's, not sure how to do the next step...

Thx
Matt.

```
<?php
$username = "MelbournePollen";
$count = 5;
$tweet=json_decode(file_get_contents("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/".$username.".json?count=".$count."" ));

for ($i=1; $i <= $count; $i++){
    //Assign feed to $feed
    $feed = $tweet[($i-1)]->text;
    echo date("M \- j",strtotime($tweet[($i-1)]->created_at)). " -- " .$feed. "</br>";
    }?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should steer you in the right direction, building on your logic (my code is untested):

```
<?php
    $username = "MelbournePollen";
    $count = 5;
    $tweet=json_decode(file_get_contents("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/".$username.".json?count=".$count."" ));

    $tweets = array();
    for ($i=1; $i <= $count; $i++){
        //Assign feed to $feed
        $feed = $tweet[($i-1)]->text;
        $time_between = time() - strtotime($tweet[($i-1)]->created_at);
        $twenty4hours = 60 * 60 * 24;
        if($time_between <= $twenty4hours)
        {
            $tweets[] = $tweet;
        }
    } 
    //Use $tweets array as needed
?>
```